# Regex allowing < and >

Tags: javascript, regex

Can anyone tell me why this regex is allowing  `<` and `>` ?

```
function IsValidPassword(password) {
    var regex = /^[A-Za-z0-9^\~^\!@/#^\$^\%&^\*+-_()]*$/; /* AlphaNumerics.  ~ (Tilde) (All "Shifts" 1-0)  underscore plus and minus */
    return regex.test(password);
}
```

My goal is

- AlphaNumerics.  (Upper and Lower).
- Tilde
- Everything in the "SHIFT" area, 1-0 on the keyboard.
- + - _

Comment: You might want to allow spaces in passwords too... and make sure this validation is also done server-side!

Comment: **Why on earth** would you restrict the characters allowed in a password?! This has made me **furious** so many times! "Your password must be between 9 and 12 characters and contain at least three of each: lowercase letter, uppercase letter, number, and special character except +-*/=$!^'?,.-;:_§ç%&/()|{}[]. And you must sacrifice the blood of a virgin and the queen's firstborn." - Well, looks like I'm writing my password down then, since you spent so much time making sure I **won't be able to remember it!**

Comment: Because of this : https://jwwishart.wordpress.com/2009/09/29/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the-client-in-asp-net-webforms-and-mvc/

Comment: @Cameron. Yeah, I have it client and server side.  Thanks.

Comment: @Siguza.   http://keepass.info/

Comment: Alright, that looks like an actual reason. Although it baffles me that there are still technologies in use that can't even handle basic ASCII input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because when you put the second `-` (intending to check for a literal `-`), it actually represents the range between `+` and `(`, which happens to include `<` and `>`.

You simply need to escape the `-` (note also that your regex can be simplified):

```
/^[A-Za-z0-9~!@#$%^&*()+\-_]*$/
```

Answer (score 7):

```
/^[A-Za-z0-9^\~^\!@/#^\$^\%&^\*+-_()]*$/
                               ^^^--- plus to underscore
```

`<` and `>` fall within that range:

```
+   -> ascii(43)
<   -> ascii(60)
>   -> ascii(62)
_   -> ascii(95)
```

that `+-_` range also happens to include the entire uppercase alphabet, so you could remove `A-Z` from the pattern and it would STILL work.

Comment: .. and a lot more. Fix by prepending a backslash.